# How to populate a node reference field based on the selected taxonomy term?

Tags: nodes

I have two content types and one vocabulary:

1. Service Categories - different categories of jobs. (VOCABULARY as the list is small and does not change)
2. Service Tasks - tasks that relate to an individual category
3. Services - record consisting of details related to a service performed

On the services page, I have a have a term reference field that allows the user to select the category of service.  Below that I have a node reference field that I would like to have populate the related task from which to choose once the category has been selected.

Without involving programming, is there a solution to my problem?  I am new to Drupal (using version 7) but am picking up the concepts quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I would accomplish this by arranging your vocabulary like so:

- Category 1
- - Task 1
- - Task 2
- Category 2
- - Etc.

I would probably just name it Service Tasks, but that's my preference. Then use the [hierarchical select module](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select).

Enable the module and it's Taxonomy Select sub-module, then add a term reference to Services using the hierarchical select widget. Now you can choose tasks related to their parent categories without having to make all sorts of references.

Comment: Thank you very much Tommy!  That is definitely an option that I have looked into, but I'm finding some challenges that have me looking for alternatives (multiple clicks to get the module to commit selections and difficulty working with field dependencies module). I am glad to have this option in my back pocket, but still interested to see if there are alternatives.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into something similar to this. I had a Content Type called `Subsidiary`, and a related Taxonomy called `SubsidiaryType`. I was working on a map that plots out where all the offices of the Subsidiaries are (Many Offices to One Subsidiary), so I also had a `MapPoint` Content Type.

Structurally, that's the same: just as your `Service` had a `ServiceTask` through `ServiceCategory`, my `MapPoint` had a `SubsidiaryType` through `Subsidiary`.

I installed the [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module, and that enables me to use a view to populate a select list in a Content Type.

Add a new View and choose the 'References' type, as well as the 'Fields' Row Setting.

Add the relationship for the Taxonomy terms, and add two fields:

- Title (Or whatever Human Readable ID you have)
- Term Name (but hide this)

Next, open the settings for the References List Format. You'll see a grouping option. Group by the Term name on the relationship.

Now, head back to the Content Type definition for Service, and add a field for Service Task. Choose `Node Reference` and then instead of using one of the presupplied relations, use a view.

Select the View we just created, and you should now have a select list that has grouped options. Here's an example of how it should look:

- **Web Development**

  - HTML/CSS Markup
  - Server Administration
  - PHP/JS Programming
- **Marketing**

  - Sales Call
  - Copy Writing
- **Administration**

  - Process Development
  - Meetings